# How to use arrayformula in Google sheets with transpose

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I am importing the landing page text from a website where the URL is stored in c2.

```
TRANSPOSE(
   QUERY(
    TRANSPOSE(
      IMPORTXML(
         c2,
         "//body[text()]"
      )
    ),
    ,
    1000
   )
 )
```

How do I do this for URLS in cells c2:c50?
I tried an arrayformula but it throws an error message

```
ARRAYFORUMULA(TRANSPOSE(
   QUERY(
    TRANSPOSE(
      IMPORTXML(
         c2:C50,
         "//body[text()]"
      )
    ),
    ,
    1000
   )
 )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: what says the error? share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

yor options are:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 IMPORTXML(C2, "//body[text()]"); 
 IMPORTXML(C3, "//body[text()]"); 
 IMPORTXML(C4, "//body[text()]"); 
 ...; 
 IMPORTXML(C50, "//body[text()]")}),,9^9))
```

### update:

```
={
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C2, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C3, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C4, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C5, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C6, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C7, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C8, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C9, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C10, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C11, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C12, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C13, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C14, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C15, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C16, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C17, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C18, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C19, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C20, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C21, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C22, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C23, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C24, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C25, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C26, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C27, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C28, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C29, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C30, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C31, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C32, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C33, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C34, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C35, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C36, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C37, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C38, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C39, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C40, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C41, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C42, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C43, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C44, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C45, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C46, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C47, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C48, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C49, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9)); 
 IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IMPORTXML(C50, "//body[text()]"))),,9^9))}
```

either way you need to use constructed array `{}`

Comment: [Constructed arrays](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en#:~:text=An%20array%20is%20a%20table,Some%20functions%20return%20arrays.) are a way in Google Sheets to display a range of value (an array) within a specific formula (in your case within ```TRANSPOSE```).

Comment: Thanks, @Player0. I tried both and still got an error message. This is the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LK6PhlT9Wk17Js22dmta4Vn9Yf2Nhm44-RfuUofGa9A/edit#gid=0